# MongoDB - avoid "downtime" during import?

Tags: mongodb, replication, mlab

I am using MongoLab to store 60 datasets that update a few times per month.
I currently have an import script that drops the database and then reimports the 60 or so CSV files.

```
//drop -> then insert each indicator
db.dropDatabase(function(err, result){
.... 
db.collection("indicators").insert(group, grpCallback);
```

During import, this obviously yields X minutes with an empty/non-complete database.

What are some options for avoiding this "downtime" using either the single instance I have today or a more advanced MongoDB configuration?

Comment: This is "really broad" actually. A fair thing to ask and I would love to answer, but I feel this is more like a series of articles rather than something with a definitive answer as suited to this site. There are just so many factors  to consider, especially in an "Advanced Configuration" as you mention. A good option "right now" might be to "throttle" the effect of the load placed by insertions. It's probably the most simple approach as well, and might suit you for some time. Kudos for considering the implications though.

Comment: Side-note: MongoDB 3.x supports "collection level locking" as opposed to "database level locking" in the default MMAPv1 engine. It also offers the WiredTiger storage engine which supports "document level locking". This may help you with concurrency issues if you have not already considered that. So still way to broad, but since you are thinking of these things already, then that is something else to consider.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn! Definitely a broad question, still your pointers are very helpful to many MongoDB newcomers I believe.

Comment: That is why I gave them. The question is likely to be eventually closed due to the broad nature or possibly receive some responses that are less than accurate. But I personally gave my upvote for the consideration you showed to the issues resulting from such operations. Definitely "food for thought" for a longer topic response in a "blog" record to cover what you are asking here.

Comment: @dani how large is your data set (in MB/GB?)

Comment: @Chris Chang: about 200 MB of csv files imported as "metadata" (separate collections) and statdata (1 collection). Thanks.

Comment: @dani so the data fits on a Sandbox plan. if you're trying to stay with a free set up, you could "switch" between 2 sandboxes. import data into 1, configure your application to use that. once you have more up-to-date data, import that into sandbox #2, then once the import is done you can make the cut over by changing the connection string in your app. not the most elegant, but a possible solution. otherwise, our Dedicated plans allow for the creation of multiple databases.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisChang. I am on the single-node plan ($15). Not sure how I can dynamically point the app (or a balance/proxy) inbetween to the instance/db that is currently stable when I do the import ...?

Comment: @dani Ah, what I was suggesting implied an app bounce once you wanted to change databases. If you write into our support I can see if our team can brainstorm any potential alternatives.